# Nodejs - Express - Socket.io How to send a message to a specific socket.id from an outside function?

Tags: node.js

I'm having problem finding the right answer for this. I'm trying to send a message to a specific socket.id given I'm handling multiple users but I need to do it from another function which does not have access to socket.io.

I need to send the message to the specific socket.id inside the function:

```
var authorizePublish = function(client, topic, payload, callback) {
//here
}
```

socketLib.js

```
/// Import Modules ///
const mosca = require('mosca');
const DeviceService = require('../services/device.service');
const config = require('../config');
const util = require('../modules/util.js');

module.exports = async function(httpServer, sessionParser) {
    var io = require("socket.io")(httpServer); // For Sockets

    io.use(function(socket, next) {
        sessionParser(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
    });

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        const userSessionId = socket.request.session.userId;
        const userId = socket.request.session.passport.user;
        const socketId = socket.request.session.id;
        if (userSessionId == '') 
            console.log('client connected');
        console.log(`Client connected: ${userSessionId}, with userid: ${userId}, with socket: ${socketId} conectado`);

        socket.on('msg:message', async function (data) {
            socket.emit('message', data);
        });          

        socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
            console.log('user disconnected');
        });
    });

    /// Mosca  Settings ///
    var moscaServer = null;
    var moscaSettings = {  
        interfaces: [ { type: "mqtt", port: 1884 }, { type: "http", port: 5000, bundle: true, static: './' }
    ],};
    var debug = util.isDebug(),
        isAuth = util.isAuth()

    //// Mosca Server ////
    var dbHost = config.dbHost;
    moscaServer = new mosca.Server(moscaSettings); 
    moscaServer.on('ready', setup);

    var authenticate = function(client, username, callback) {
      console.log('-------- Authenticating MQTT user... --------');

      callback(null, flag);

      if(authenticate) client.user = username; 
    }

    /// Mosca Events ///
    moscaServer.on('published', function (packet, client) {
        var arr = packet.topic.split('/');
        if (arr.length !== 3) { return; }
    });

    /// Mosca Functions ///
    var authorizePublish = function(client, topic, payload, callback) {
      if (client.user == topic.split('/')[1]) {

        // socket.emit('message', payload.toString());  (Here is where I need to get access to the client socket.id in order to send him a message with the payload.

        callback(null, true);
      }
      else {
        callback(null, false);
      }

    }

    function setup() {
    if (isAuth) {
        moscaServer.authenticate = authenticate;
    }
    if (config.authPub === true) {
        moscaServer.authorizePublish = authorizePublish;
    }
    if(config.authSubs == true) {
        moscaServer.authorizeSubscribe = authorizeSubscribe;
    }
    console.log('Mosca server is up and running')
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the way you send to a specific socket id is with this:

```
io.to(id).emit(msg, data);
```

where `id` is the `socket.id` of the socket.io connection that you want to send to.

Or, you could put that into a function:

```
function sendToId(id, msg, data) {
    io.to(id).emit(msg, data);
}
```

So, secondly to be able to do that from anywhere you have a couple options:

1. You can import the `io` instance and use it with the above line of code.
2. You can export a function called something like `sendToId()` from a module that does have access to the `io` instance and then you can import that function in order to be able to use it.
3. You can assign the `io` instance to a known object so that anyone with access to that more popularly known object can then retrieve it from there.  An example of that is to set it as a properly on the Express `app` object as in `app.set("io", io)` and then anyone with access to the `app` object can you `let io = app.get("io");` to get it and use it.

Comment: Thank you! I understood what you said, I have solved it in some other way after understand the concept you presented in here.